# How to display multiple values in one column depending on foreign key in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

Hey guys I have two MySQL tables:

*main-table:*
[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuSn9.png)

and *secondary table:* [users_phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4cDX.png)

Each user can have multiple phone numbers - in the second SQL table user_id is the foreign key pointing to the main table's users ids. I am trying to list in a JSP table all of the users with each user's phone numbers, but I can't achieve that.

Here's what I came up so far:

User POJO:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;   
    private List<String> userPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();    
    
    public User() { }    
    
    public User(String username, String email, String password, List<String> userPhoneNumbers) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userPhoneNumbers = userPhoneNumbers;
    }
    
    // Getters and Setters
        
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +    
                "} \n";
    }
}
```

Phone Numbers POJO:

```
public class PhoneNumbers {
    private int idPhone;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int idUser;
    
    public PhoneNumbers() { }

    // Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPhone{" + "idPhone=" + idPhone + ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber
                + ", idUser=" + idUser + '\'' + "}\n";
    }
}
```

UserDAO:

```
public class UserDao {
   
    private static final String FIND_ALL_USERS_QUERY = 
            "SELECT *"
            + " FROM users"
            + " INNER JOIN users_phone_nums"
            + " ON users.id = users_phone_nums.user_id";    
    
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return getUsers(-1, FIND_ALL_USERS_QUERY);
    }  

    private List<User> getUsers(int id, String query) {
        try (Connection conn = DbUtil.getConnection()) {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            if (id != -1) {
                statement.setInt(1, id);
            }

            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    user.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
                    user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
                    user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));                   

                    PhoneNumbers phoneNumbers = new PhoneNumbers();
                    phoneNumbers.setPhoneNumber(resultSet.getString("phone_number"));
                    phoneNumbers.setIdUser(resultSet.getInt("user_id"));
                    
                    System.out.println("############ " + phoneNumbers);
                    System.out.println("----->>>>> " + user);
                    
                    
                    users.add(user);
                }
                return users;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

UserServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/user")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        request.setAttribute("users", userDao.findAll());

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/web/user/listUsers.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

and here is the JSP:

```
<table id="usersTableId">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>           
            <th>user phone</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.username}</td>
                <td>${user.email}</td>                
                <td>${user.password}</td>
                <td>How to list user's phone numbers?</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone explain to me how can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change the type of userPhoneNumbers in the User class from list to string; and prepare a comma separated string of phone numbers.
(Also suggest renaming the `PhoneNumbers` pojo to `PhoneNumber`.)

```
StringBuilder phoneNums = new StringBuilder()
PhoneNumbers phoneNumbers = new PhoneNumbers();

for(PhoneNumbers phoneNumber : phoneNumbers) {
   phoneNums.append(resultSet.getString("phone_number")).append(", ");
}
user.setPhoneNumbers(phoneNums.toString());
```

Now in JSP you can print this comma separated string value.

Another alternative is to continue setting it as list and  have another `c:foreach` to loop through it in JSP

Comment: yes I wanted to achieve it the second way, with c:foreach loop, but when I tried, I only got an empty array and this first way it isn't working I've tried it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: didn't read the question properly apols;

```
<td>${custom.userid}</td>
<td>${custom.username}</td>
<td>${custom.email}</td>                
<td>${custom.password}</td>
<td>
    <c:forEach items="${custom.numbers}" var="number">
        <div class="stylethisyo">
            ${number}
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</td>
```

this would work, just need to loop the subset right?

EDIT 2: I also would probably keep my models separate. So would have an object for user, and for numbers. Then when mapping them, I wouldn't create an object with the same data in multiple times, it would only ever be a list of CustomObjects with user details, and a list of numbers.

You can acheive this by looking up the Users, then in the while loop looking up numbers for that User with the PreparedStatement class and adding them to the CustomObject.

Comment: well I figured out this but in this case you loop through the whole subset, my idea is to loop over one user's phones - for example user 1 has 3 phone numbers - on each user's row show only his/hers phones, not the whole subset.

Comment: Yes, Bajal's answer shows you one way to do this, and mine shows another. You need to think more about how you're going to show the data, if you join the two tables in the way you're currently doing it, you'll have redundant user data on each line for each number, but if you split the query, you can assign the list to the Users object easily.